# Redis: Efficient cluster of servers for large key set

Tags: redis

I have a very large set of keys, 200M keys, with small values, <100 bytes, to store and I'm trying to use Redis.  The problem is such that I have 10 Redis DB to split the keys over, but currently I'm on a single server with those 10 Redis DB.  By a Redis DB I mean using `SELECT`.
  From my calculations it looks like I'm going to blow out memory.  I think I'll need over 4TB of memory for this case!  What are my options?  First, my calculation is based on 10000 keys with 100 byte values taking 220MB of RAM (this is from a table I found).
  So simply put `(2*10^8 / 10^4) * 220MB = 4.4TB`.

If my calculation looks correct, what are my options? I've read on different posts that Redis VM is no longer an option.  Can I use a Redis cluster?  This still appears to require too many servers to be practical.
  I understand I could switch to another DB, but I'd like that to be the last resort option.

Comment: Have you tried to use multiple keys into a single hash? This can cut memory usage 10 times.

Comment: I am reviewing hashing / compression strategies.  Perhaps I should post a question just on this topic?  I did not give the details on the problem, but it is interesting.  We are doing an S3 endpoint, so a key is a user-given "path" and the value is our internal object "path".  The key can be anything within 256 chars. The value we have to turn into a real file path, but it is under our total control.  In other words some kind of pointer needs to get us to retrieve the file.  So I can use compression or hashing techniques to reduce the database.  That's the next step.

Comment: That sounds like a neat project and if you gain any insights (or want to hash (:)) out ideas) please share with the [redis-db mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/redis-db) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, using shared databases (i.e. the `SELECT` command) isn't a recommended practice since all of these databases are essentially managed by the same Redis process. It is preferable having 10 separate Redis processes (even on the same server) in order to avoid contention (more info [here](https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances)).

Next, there are ways to reduce the memory footprint of your database. You could, for example, perform client-side compression (see [here](http://labs.octivi.com/how-we-cut-down-memory-usage-by-82/)) or consider other optimizations such as using Hashes to keep multiple values (as described [here](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization)).

That said, a Redis server is ultimately bound by the amount of RAM that the host provides. Once you've reached that limit you'll need to shard your database and use a Redis cluster. Since you're already using multiple databases this shouldn't pose a big challenge as your code should already be compatible with that to a degree. Sharding can be done in one of three approaches: client, proxy or Redis Cluster. Client-side sharding can be implemented in your code or by the Redis client that you're using (if the client library that you're using supports that). [Redis Cluster (v3)](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) is expected to be released in the very near future and already has a stable release candidate. As for proxy-based sharding, there are several open source solutions out there, including [Twitter's twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy), [Netflix's dynomite](https://github.com/Netflix/dynomite) and [codis](https://github.com/wandoulabs/codis). Additional information about sharding and partitioning can be found [here](http://redis.io/topics/partitioning).

Disclaimer: I work at Redis Labs. Lastly, AFAIK there's only one Redis-as-a-Service provider that already provides built-in support for clustering Redis. Redis Labs' [Redis Cloud](https://redislabs.com/redis-cloud) is a fully-managed service that can scale seamlessly to any required capacity. Our clusters support both the '{}' hashtag standard as well as sharding by RegEx - more about this can be found [here](https://redislabs.com/blog/new-redis-cloud-clusters-with-regular-expression-sharding).

Answer (score 0):

You can use LMDB with Dynomite to store data beyond your memory capacity. LMDB uses both disk and memory to store data.  Dynomite make LMDB to be distributed.

We have done a POC with this combo and they work nicely together.

For more information, please check out our open issue here:
https://github.com/Netflix/dynomite/issues/254